# FInd float numbers that have at least two multiples in given list

Tags: python, math

I need a function to find all float numbers that have at least two multiples in a given list.

Do you know if an already existing and efficient function exists in pandas, scipy or numpy for this purpose?

#### Example of expected behavior

Given the list `[3.3, 3.4, 4.4, 5.1]`, I want a function that returns `[.2, .3, 1.1, 1.7]`

Comment: The concept of divisor for real numbers is quite ambiguous. Even more with float number with a given precision. You mean numbers with a finite number of decimals ?

Comment: yes sure, let's say 1 decimal

Comment: I think you would also want 0.3 and 0.2 since 0.3*11 = 3.3 and 0.3*17 = 5.1; and 0.2*14 = 3.4 and 0.2*22 = 4.4 ?

Comment: you are right!!

Comment: probably the solution is to multiply all numbers times 10 (in this case) find divisors of all numbers in list and then divide back by 10. Then select elements with at least two occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
import itertools
from itertools import chain
from math import sqrt

l = [3.3, 3.4, 4.4, 5.1]

def divisors(n):
    # Find all divisors
    return set(chain.from_iterable((i,n//i) for i in range(1,int(sqrt(n))+1) if n%i == 0))

# Multiply all numbers by 10, make integer, concatenate all divisors from all numbers
divisors_all = list(itertools.chain(*[list(divisors(int(x*10))) for x in l])) 

# Take divisors with more than 2 multiples, then multiply by 10 back
div, counts = np.unique(divisors_all, return_counts=True)
result = div[counts > 1]/10
```

Output:

```
array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 1.7])
```

This makes the hypothesis that all number have one decimal maximum in the original set.

This keeps 1 as it divides everything, but can be removed easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`numpy.gcd()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gcd.html) can be used to do what your question asks subject to the following clarifying constraints:

- the input numbers will be examined to 1 decimal precision
- inputs must be > 0
- results must be > 1.0

```py
import numpy as np
a = [3.3, 3.4, 4.4, 5.1]
b = [int(10*x) for x in a]
res = {np.gcd(x, y) for i, x in enumerate(b) for j, y in enumerate(b) if i != j}
res = [x/10 for x in res if x > 10]
```

Output:

```
[1.1, 1.7]
```

**UPDATE**:

To exactly match the results in the question after edit by OP (namely: `[.2, .3, 1.1, 1.7]`), we can do this:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [3.3, 3.4, 4.4, 5.1]
b = [int(10*x) for x in a]
res = sorted({np.gcd(x, y) / 10 for i, x in enumerate(b) for j, y in enumerate(b) if i != j} - {1 / 10})
```

Output:

```
[0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 1.7]
```

Comment: why the output does not contain .2 and .3 as suggested by @PlainRavioli?

Comment: It looks like you edited your question just a minute ago to change the output specification. My answer was targeting the desired output specified in your original post. If you prefer the output in the answer by @PlainRavioli, you can simply change the final line in my code to be `res = [x/10 for x in res]`, eliminating the filter to remove results that are `< 1.0`.